# Timers in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7, timer

I need a timer in Windows 7 that calls a function when the time interval has elapsed and does not block the threat it is on.  In other words, I can't use `delay()`.

I've been trying to use `IMFTimer` to generate a callback with the following code:

```
IMFTimer *playbackEndTimer;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(IMFTimer), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&playbackEndTimer));
```

`CoCreateInstance` returns "class not registered".  It also looks like I will need to use `IMFAsyncCallback` as the callback, and I have not been able to figure out how to do that from the documentation.

Is there a better way? Can somebody point me to some working source code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you already have a window with a message loop, it would not be difficult integrate into your existing code.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I already found that.  It's working in a DLL, not a window, but that just means I needed a function pointer.

Comment: Um, `IMFTimer` is an interface, not a coclass.

Comment: What's the difference?  How do I set up an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was a somewhat stupid question.  I should have used the old SetTimer() without trying to use IMFTimer::SetTimer().  Problem solved.